# Merge JSON coverage reports from Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, istanbul

I'm currently collecting coverage for modules within a Lerna monorepo. Within each `package.json` I run `jest --coverage --json --outputFile someDir`.

This creates multiple JSON reports, with a schema like:

```
{
  "numFailedTestSuites": 0,
  "numFailedTests": 0,
  "numPassedTestSuites": 0,
  "numPassedTests": 18,
  "numPendingTestSuites": 0,
  "numPendingTests": 0,
  "numRuntimeErrorTestSuites": 0,
  "numTodoTests": 0,
  "numTotalTestSuites": 8,
  "numTotalTests": 18,
  "openHandles": [],
  "snapshot": {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

I want to merge all of these outputs into one JSON report at the root directory. My main objective is to collect and report the coverage through a GitHub Actions workflow (which needs the `--json` report from Jest).

I've been attempting to use Istanbul to merge this, however, it seems to only work with the coverage maps, so with the `coverage-final.json` file which is produced.

When I try to merge from the JSON reports produced, I get:

```
Error: Coverage must be initialized with a path or an object
```

I assume this is because the schema is incorrect.

Comment: Can you parse the JSON files, merge them serialize the merged data? Would this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In order to merge multiple JSON reports from Jest into a single report, you can use the `istanbul-merge` tool provided by Istanbul. However, as you mentioned, Istanbul typically works with coverage maps and the `coverage-final.json` file.

To merge the Jest `JSON` reports, you'll need to convert them into the Istanbul-compatible coverage format. Here's an example workflow you can follow:

Install the required packages by running the following command in your project's root directory:

```
npm install --save-dev istanbul istanbul-merge
```

Create a new script in your project's package.json file to handle the merging process. Add the following script under the scripts section:

```
"scripts": {
  "merge-coverage": "node merge-coverage.js"
}
```

Create a new file named `merge-coverage.j`s in your project's root directory. This file will contain the code to merge the JSON reports. Add the following code to `merge-coverage.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const istanbul = require('istanbul');
const merge = require('istanbul-merge');

const mergedReportPath = './coverage/merged-report.json'; // Adjust the output path as needed
const reportPaths = [
  // Specify the paths of your individual Jest JSON reports
  './path/to/report1.json',
  './path/to/report2.json',
  // Add more report paths as needed
];

// Load the reports
const reports = reportPaths.map((reportPath) => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(reportPath, 'utf8')));

// Merge the reports
const mergedReport = merge.createCoverageMap();

for (const report of reports) {
  const coverageMap = istanbul.createCoverageMap(report);
  mergedReport.merge(coverageMap);
}

// Write the merged report to a file
fs.writeFileSync(mergedReportPath, JSON.stringify(mergedReport.toJSON(), null, 2));

console.log('Coverage reports merged successfully!');
```

Run the merging script by executing the following command:

```
npm run merge-coverage
```

This will execute the `merge-coverage` script and generate the merged coverage report at the specified mergedReportPath.

You can now use the merged report file (`merged-report.json`) for your GitHub Actions workflow or any other coverage reporting purposes.

With above steps, you should be able to merge the individual Jest JSON reports into a single JSON report using `Istanbul` and generate the desired coverage report for your GitHub Actions workflow.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like ChatGPT